# Audio stops after playing video and setting app to background on iOS 11

Tags: video, background, avplayer, ios11, avplayerviewcontroller

I am using AVPlayer and AVPlayerViewController to playback music and video respectively in my app. Following are the steps to reproduce my problem:

1. Play a video in the app
2. Quit the video
3. Play a song in the app
4. Set the app to background
5. When the song finishes, the audio player cannot playback the next song automatically. It just stops at the very beginning of the next song.

This issue (cannot play next song automatically) is seen on iOS 11 only, but not on iOS 9 or 10. Also, without playing video everything works fine. Does anyone see the same problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The link with the video seems odd. I'm guessing you are aware of and following apples rules for background tasks (if not it might be to do with tightening the enforcement here): https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: Yes I am aware of those Apple's rules. I found that I have to enable some commands of MPRemoteCommandCenter to get back the control.